# Keyboard keys still messed up after changing locale

Tags: pi-4, keyboard, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm, locale

Some keys on the keyboard output the wrong characters even after going to Prefs > Raspberry Pi Configuration > Localisation and setting the locale to US, timezone to NY, keyboard to Generic 105 key pc. Rebooted.

Instead of `\` I get `#`

Instead of `|` I get `~`

Instead of `~` I get `¬`

Instead of `@` I get `"`

Instead of `"` I get `@`

There are a few others.

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to set locale character set from "ISO-8859-x" to "UTF-8" in Prefs > Raspberry Pi Configuration > Localisation. Didn't know what these terms mean I so hadn't set them correctly.